# Angular2 getOptional of undefined polyfills

Tags: angular

I get this error whenever I try to load my ang2 app.

```
angular2-polyfills.js:1243 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getOptional' of undefined
Error loading http://localhost:8081/app/boot.js
at _runAppInitializers (http://localhost:8081/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:12628:25)
at PlatformRef_._initApp (http://localhost:8081/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:12603:21)
at PlatformRef_.application (http://localhost:8081/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:12550:22)
at Object.bootstrap (http://localhost:8081/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:24805:64)
at execute (http://localhost:8081/app/boot.js:36:23)
at ensureEvaluated (http://localhost:8081/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3186:26)
at Object.execute (http://localhost:8081/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3304:13)
at doDynamicExecute (http://localhost:8081/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:703:25)
at link (http://localhost:8081/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:905:20)
at doLink (http://localhost:8081/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:557:7)
```

I've tried adding and switching the shim es6 js with other scripts in the index file, but that didn't help. After I pulled the newest version from the repo, this error started appearing. I reverted back to my own version as I couldn't find any changes from my colleagues that would give me this problem, but somehow the error didn't go away. Their version doesn't have the error.
I've also tried to remove each service and provider from the bootstrap in boot.ts. No errors popping up. but the second I put those provider and strategy back in, the 'getOptional of undefined' started appearing again.

```js
/**
 * boot.ts
 */

import {AppComponent}     from './app.component';
import {bootstrap}        from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/http";
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS,RouteConfig,RouteParams,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from "angular2/router";
import {CardService} from "./game/card/card.service";
import {provide} from "angular2/core";
import {ThemeService} from "../app/game/theme/theme.service"
import {OrganisationService} from "./game/organisation/organisation.service";
import {UserService} from "./game/user/user.service";
import {SocketService} from "./helpercomponents/SocketService";
bootstrap(AppComponent,[
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}),
    CardService,
    ThemeService,
    UserService,
    OrganisationService
]);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Kandoe</title>
  <base href="/" />
  <script src="./node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="./node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="./node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
  <script src="./node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
  <script src="./node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
  <script src="./node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.2.0/dropzone.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sockjs-client/1.0.3/sockjs.js"></script>

  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/login-register.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/organisation-detail-browse.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/dropzone.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/game.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/circle-session.css">
  <script>
    System.config({
      packages: {
        app: {
          format: 'register',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
      }
    });
    System.import('app/boot')
      .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you change all your double quotes to single quotes in your imports, does it work? There's an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7433) about mixing single and double quotes. Worth to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't exactly figure out what the cause was, but changing es6 to es5 in the tsconfig made it work again.